# pandas group by on column values and get count

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have result, student, version and status columns. in this I want to do group by using Student , Version and result = pass count and result = fail count

similarly like **df.groupby(["student", "version",  "result=pass"]).size().reset_index(name="new_result")**

the below is my data frame

| result | student | version | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| pass | Student-A | L-1.0 | Active |
| fail | Student-A | L-1.0 | Active |
| fail | Student-A | L-1.0 | Active |
| pass | Student-A | M-1.0 | Active |
| fail | Student-A | M-1.0 | Active |
| pass | Student-B | N-1.0 | Active |
| pass | Student-B | N-1.0 | Active |
| pass | Student-B | N-1.0 | Active |
| pass | Student-C | O-1.0 | Active |
| pass | Student-C | O-1.0 | Active |
| fail | Student-C | O-1.0 | Active |
| fail | Student-C | P-1.0 | Active |
| fail | Student-C | P-1.0 | Active |

I want my output data frame as below:

| student | version | pass_count | fail_count | status | total_count (pass+fail) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Student-A | L-1.0 | 1 | 2 | Active | 3 |
| Student-A | M-1.0 | 1 | 1 | Active | 2 |
| Student-B | N-1.0 | 3 | 0 | Active | 3 |
| Student-C | O-1.0 | 1 | 1 | Active | 2 |
| Student-C | P-1.0 | 0 | 2 | Active | 2 |

I am able to get pass and fail count using the below but not total count, anyone pls help

```
pd.pivot_table(master_df, index=['status', 'student', 'version'], columns=['result'], aggfunc=len, fill_value=0)
```

Comment: Try using the df.pivot_table to do the above case.

Comment: @Roxy, I am not familiar with pivot_table, could you pls help with some reference code or may be the exact code pls

Comment: I am able to get pass and fail count using the below but not total count, anyone pls help

pd.pivot_table(master_df, index=['status', 'student', 'version'], columns=['result'], aggfunc=len, fill_value=0)

Comment: You need to provide sample data for us to recreate the issue.

Comment: See below code for getting the total count

Comment: Slightly revised the codes to reformat the table.  Please check the update.

Comment: As new requirement with new column has been posted to [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69328339/pandas-group-by-on-column-values-and-extract-one-column-text), the new edit (posted 3 weeks after the question had been completed) is reverted back to the completed version for better matching the question and answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the total count, you can use:

```
df.groupby(["student", "version"])['result'].count().reset_index(name='total_count')
```

**Result:**

```
     student version  total_count
0  Student-A   L-1.0            3
1  Student-A   M-1.0            2
2  Student-B   N-1.0            3
3  Student-C   O-1.0            3
4  Student-C   P-1.0            2
```

Or, if you want to get it based on your pivot table, you can use:

```
df2 = pd.pivot_table(df, index=['status', 'student', 'version'], columns=['result'], aggfunc=len, fill_value=0).reset_index().rename_axis(columns=None)

df2['total_count'] = df2['fail'] + df2['pass']
```

**Result:**

```
print(df2)

   status    student version  fail  pass  total_count
0  Active  Student-A   L-1.0     2     1            3
1  Active  Student-A   M-1.0     1     1            2
2  Active  Student-B   N-1.0     0     3            3
3  Active  Student-C   O-1.0     1     2            3
4  Active  Student-C   P-1.0     2     0            2
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @seaBean, it worked exactly as per my requirement, thanks a lot for your support. cheers

Comment: @user3202086   Welcome!  Pleased to help!  Happy programming & have a nice day! :-)

Comment: in the above table, I have one more column called "Failed subjects" in that every student failed subjects is mentioned so I want output as below

 Active      Student-A       L-1.0       2        1               3        maths, Science

Comment: can you pls help me on this ?

Comment: @user3202086  It's difficult to understand your new data structure just by a few words in the comment here.   It would be better if you could post a new question with the data structure with sample data and the desired output based on the sample data.  You can advise me here after you posted the question and I will try my best to have a look if I can.

Comment: I have modified this question with my new requirement. I have added failed Subject column in the input and proposed output as well.. Could you pls help me now, please

Comment: @user3202086  That's a brand new question unrelated to the original question. I'm afraid it's not a good practice to modify a completed question with your new question and require new answer.  Please post a separate question on that.

Comment: posted new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69328339/pandas-group-by-on-column-values-and-extract-one-column-text

Could you pls help , pls

Comment: @user3202086  Posted an answer to the new question. Please take a look.