# pandas group by on column values and extract one column text

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have result, student, version and status columns. in this I want to do group by using Student , Version and result = pass count and result = fail count

similarly like **df.groupby(["student", "version",  "result=pass"]).size().reset_index(name="new_result")**

the below is my data frame

| result | student | version | status | Failed Subject |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| pass | Student-A | L-1.0 | Active |  |
| fail | Student-A | L-1.0 | Active | Mathematics |
| fail | Student-A | L-1.0 | Active | Physics |
| pass | Student-A | M-1.0 | Active |  |
| fail | Student-A | M-1.0 | Active | Science |
| pass | Student-B | N-1.0 | Active |  |
| pass | Student-B | N-1.0 | Active |  |
| pass | Student-B | N-1.0 | Active |  |
| pass | Student-C | O-1.0 | Active |  |
| pass | Student-C | O-1.0 | Active |  |
| fail | Student-C | O-1.0 | Active | English |
| fail | Student-C | P-1.0 | Active | Computers |
| fail | Student-C | P-1.0 | Active | Mathematics |

I want my output data frame as below:

| student | version | pass_count | fail_count | status | total_count (pass+fail) | Failed Subject |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Student-A | L-1.0 | 1 | 2 | Active | 3 | Mathematics,Physics |
| Student-A | M-1.0 | 1 | 1 | Active | 2 | Science |
| Student-B | N-1.0 | 3 | 0 | Active | 3 |  |
| Student-C | O-1.0 | 1 | 1 | Active | 2 | English |
| Student-C | P-1.0 | 0 | 2 | Active | 2 | Computers,Mathematics |

I am able to get pass and fail count using the below but not total count, anyone pls help

```
pd.pivot_table(master_df, index=['status', 'student', 'version'], columns=['result'], aggfunc=len, fill_value=0)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`.groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`agg()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html), as follows:

```
df_out = (df.groupby(['student', 'version', 'status'], as_index=False)
            .agg(**{'pass_count': ('result', lambda x: x[x == 'pass'].size),
                    'fail_count': ('result', lambda x: x[x == 'fail'].size),                    
                    'total_count': ('result', 'size'),
                    'Failed Subject': ('Failed Subject', lambda x: ','.join(x.dropna()))
                    })
          )
```

**Result:**

```
print(df_out)

     student version  status  pass_count  fail_count  total_count         Failed Subject
0  Student-A   L-1.0  Active           1           2            3    Mathematics,Physics
1  Student-A   M-1.0  Active           1           1            2                Science
2  Student-B   N-1.0  Active           3           0            3                       
3  Student-C   O-1.0  Active           2           1            3                English
4  Student-C   P-1.0  Active           0           2            2  Computers,Mathematics
```